# Dynamically percentage width assignment with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've got a simple piece of jQuery running to assign a width to my list items:

```
    $(subMenu).each( function() {
        var noLi        = $(this).children('li').length,
            itemSize    = (10/noLi)*10;
        $(this).children('li').each( function() {
            $(this).css('width', itemSize +'%');
        });
    });
```

I know there are always less than 10 list-items in this case so I am generating the percentage width by the simple `itemSize` calculation. However if more items were added, the whole thing would fail & the layout would not be as intended.

I also believe this may not be the most efficient way to achieve this in the first place, but am unsure of a better way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `itemSize = Math.min((noLi/10)*100, 100);`?

Comment: i would make them responsive, not always 10 across. this means floating and fitting as many cols on the screen as is readable, typically using ems for width instead of percentage.

Comment: Uh, I don't think so... Well, at the moment I have 7 items. So 7/10 = ~1.4286 by multiplying it by 10 this makes 1.4286%... which if you multiply by 7 equals 100. I think that maths is correct?

Comment: No, 7 / 10 is definitely less than 1 ;)

Comment: @dandavis that would be ideal, however I'm creating a sub navigation that appears with an animation. (Very much like this: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalSlideOutMenu/) But because I'm using Wordpress I cannot do this just with CSS

Comment: Oh, I see - you're trying to consume the width using x number of items. Sorry, I thought you were trying to calculate like a progress bar or something. Still, 7 / 10 is definitely not 1.42... :) LOL

Comment: @Steve, you're definitely not wrong there (is it obvious I've been working for too long!?)

Comment: width: calc( 100% / 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean itemSize gets to big? If so, you can do this:

```
itemSize = Math.min(100, (10/noLi)*10); // Get smallest value of the two. 100 is the max now
```

About adding sizes, you can replace the code to this:

```
 $(this).children('li').css('width', itemSize +'%'); // no need for each
```

Combined would be:

```
$(subMenu).each( function() {
    var $AllLi  = $(this).children('li'); // Save'm all for later access
    var noLi    = $AllLi.length; // we saved all selected li´s so we dont need to reselect
    itemSize    = Math.min(100, (10/noLi)*10);
    $AllLi.css('width', itemSize +'%'); // no need for each
});
```

---

Another way might be better, using css:

```
<style>
    ul{
        width: 100%; 
        display: table-row;
    }
    li{
        display: table-cell;
    }
    li:gt(10){
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>li part</li>
    <li>li part</li>
    <li>li part</li>
    <li>li part</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use Math.min to avoid the extra condition.

Comment: Thanks. Native JS isnt my best area, I like this. Added it my code

Comment: Ooooh CSS would be ideal. Will try to implement & shall feedback momentarily.

Comment: If css doesnt work, do you have more than 1 `submenu`? If not, you can remove that each and change the $allLi to something like `$('#subMenu').children('li')`

Comment: FYI, I believe `display: table-cell` is IE8+ if that's an issue. http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3Atable-cell

Comment: Yeah there are 2 `submenu`

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to make any assumptions about how many items you're going to have. If you just want to divide the 100% width into x number of items, you can simply use `100 / x`.

Also, there is no need for the nested `.each` you have. jQuery does that automatically.

```
$(subMenu).each(function() {
    var items = $(this).children('li');
    var itemSize = 100 / items.length;
    items.css('width', itemSize +'%');
});
```